# Code conversion from 2.0 to 1.0

Tags: xcode, swift, barcode

I am developing a bar code scanner on XCode 6.4.1
Here's Swift 2.0 Code:

```
do {
   videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
} catch {
   return
}
```

Can you tell me the replacement of "do, try & catch" in swift 1.0

Answer (score 1):

```
if let videoInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice) {
  //videoInput available
} else {
  return 
}
```